# In Dynamic CRM how to track export data from report

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

My requirement is to get  the event when user click the save button and export data to excel or word to register some plugin code. I need to create some tracker record.

[image]

Comment: Since you are supposedly dealing with on on-premise environment, I'd look into parsing SSRS logs instead.

Comment: We are having online environment

Comment: In that case the [tag:dynamics-crm-2016] tag is surly wrong because I doubt Microsoft still offers this version in the cloud. Also there will be no possibility to receive an CRM event for this button action since this is the Report Server UI and beyond the reach of any customizing.

Comment: Look at any out of the box Reports provided by Dynamics 365, It will have Footer as Prepraed by that means the user who ran the report. Does it make sense for you?

Comment: I think running reports bypasses the `RetrieveMultiple` message so it's not possible to track using CRM events (plugins/workflows)